# Stuck while iterating the dictionary in the django template

Tags: python, html, django

I have this dictionary:-

```
a = {'title': ['Turning a MacBook into a Touchscreen with $1 of Hardware (2018)', 'Supercentenarians are concentrated into regions with no birth certificates', 'Open list of GDPR fines so far'], 'url': ['https://www.anishathalye.com/2018/04/03/macbook-touchscreen/', 'https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/704080v1', 'https://github.com/lknik/gdpr/blob/master/fines/README.md'], 'type': ['story', 'story', 'story'], 'n': [0, 1, 2]}
```

I passed it into the template.
Now, what I want is to get the first 'title' along with the 'type', with its 'url'.
I tried the following code:-

```
<ul>
{% for i in n %}
<br/>
{{i}}
<li>{{title.i}}</li><br/>
<li>{{url.i}}</li>
{%endfor%}
```

But couldn't get the desired output.
My desired output is:-

**Title**: Turning a MacBook into a Touchscreen with $1 of **Hardware** (2018)
**URL**: https://www.anishathalye.com/2018/04/03/macbook-touchscreen/
TYPE: story

In this way a continuous list of Titles followed by url and type.

The output I get is a blank screen.
Please help me out.

Comment: Couldn't be easier for you to change this dict of lists into a list of dicts  ? -> `a = [{'title': 'blabla', 'url': 'www...', 'type':'story'} , {'title'...'}, {}]`

Comment: are you sending context to template from your views?

Comment: The context is 'a' @HemanthSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend your context like that though,
but if you don't want change it, u can use custom simple [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout).

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(my_list, idx):
    return my_list[idx]
```

then in your template (don't forget to load it first)

```
{% for item in title %}
Title: {{ item }}
URL:  {{ url|index:forloop.counter0 }}
Type: {{ type|index:forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

I recommend this way, it more be simple if you use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in your views

```
title = ['Turning a MacBook into a Touchscreen with $1 of Hardware (2018)', 'Supercentenarians are concentrated into regions with no birth certificates', 'Open list of GDPR fines so far']

url = ['https://www.anishathalye.com/2018/04/03/macbook-touchscreen/', 'https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/704080v1', 'https://github.com/lknik/gdpr/blob/master/fines/README.md']

type = ['story', 'story', 'story']

zipped = zip(title, url, type)
a = {'zipped': zipped}
```

then in your template

```
{% for title, url, type in zipped %}
Title: {{ title }}
URL: {{ url }}
Type: {{ type }}
{% endfor %}
```

or another way, use list of dictionaries instead

```
my list = [
    {'title': 'Turning a MacBook into a Touchscreen with $1 of Hardware (2018)', 'url': 'https://www.anishathalye.com/2018/04/03/macbook-touchscreen/', 'type':'story'},
    {'title': '...', 'url': '...', 'type': 'story'}, 
    {'title': '...', 'url': '...', 'type': 'story'}
]
a = {'my_list': my_list}
```

then iterate it with:

```
{% for item in my_list %}
Title: {{ item.title}}
URL: {{ item.url}}
Type: {{ item.type }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<ul>
  {% for key, values in a.items %}
    {% if key != 'n' %}
      <br/>
      <li>{{ key }}: {{ values.0}}</li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Not Working ! :(

Comment: How are you passing the dict to the template?

Comment: With this statement in views.py:- return HttpResponse(template.render(a,request)), where a is the dict mentioned above.

Comment: Ok, it'd be `a.items` then, i'll update the answer.

Comment: I tried the a.items as well, didn't work. Nothing showed up

Comment: Infact, the method which I tried, if I try to get say title.0; then it's printing the first title

Comment: @DarshanChheda updated the answer. I tested the code and it worked for me.

Comment: Still getting a blank screen.

Comment: Then you're not passing the `a` dict or it has a different format. You can verify by adding `{{a}}` to your template and see what it prints.